# Calculate Acceleration iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accelerometer, core-location

I am developing an iPhone application that is supposed to calculate acceleration in m/s. To be honest, I know I can calculate the values using the distance coordinates from the GPS, but I'm not sure if they will update as frequently as I'd like them to. With that in mind, I wanted to use the accelerometer.

The values I want to put out are going to be in m/s, i.e. 0.72m/s, etc.

What is the best way to go about this and get started?

Comment: The Event Handling Guide has a [chapter on motion events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW26) that should get you started.

Comment: Acceleration is mearsured in m/s/s (meter per square second) while m/s stands for velocity. So are you looking for velocity or acceleration?

Comment: Acceleration. Sorry about that.

Comment: You need to clarify what you want. Calculate velocity from GPS locations seems easy enough. Doing that reliably with the accelerometers is not (imo it's impossible because of gravity).

Comment: @MartinWickman, I'm not exactly sure of the best way to do this, which is why I'm asking. That's why I asked for the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [*Core Motion*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW5).

Core Motion reports acceleration in units of Earth gravity, so multiply by 9.81 to get m/s.

Comment: I just read through it but to be honest I'm not sure where to start. I might need a little hand-holding here. :/

Comment: `acceleration` has 3 property values, `x`, `y` and `z`. To get m/s should I be multiplying only the `x` value?